# comparing discrete and continuous measure performances

Tags: curve-fitting

I am trying to estimate the value of the response/dependent variable based on the Age value. First, we used the defined age intervals to estimate the dependent variable and then we considered age as a continuous predictor.
[image]
Now I am looking for a statistical method/technique to find the similarity of these two methods when it comes to measuring the healthy population. In both methods, all observations which fall between the two lines/curves can be considered healthy. I just want to know what percentage of the subjects which were identified healthy by considering age as a discrete variable, can also be considered healthy by considering age as a continuous variable as well.

Comment: How about looking at the fraction of observations that disagree between the two methods? Or you could look at the difference in distance between the cutoff for "healthy" and each observation. Do you have any ground-truth way to identify "healthy" individuals or are you trying to develop a criterion?